# Is it possible to align a mems gyro to approximately true north with no external data input?

Tags: gyro, mems, navigation

Is it possible to align a mems gyro to approximately true north with no external data input - ie nothing input by the user.  I want to put a mems gyro/acc ship on a board and mount the board to a ceiling and have it recognize the approximate direction of north, ignoring mechanical misalignments.

Comment: No compass or something? No.

Comment: Get one with a magnetometer in it, then you can do the "spin around 3 times" alignment procedure.

Comment: Do you want to put it in a stationary home? Just draw an arrow on the ceiling.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I guess some context would be nice... Quite a few years ago I had a car with a compass in the dashboard that had to be calibrated by driving around in a circle 3 times in one direction, and then 3 times in the opposite direction. Even now, [Google recommends using a "figure 8" pattern"](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) to calibrate the compass (align the magnetometers).

Comment: Go indoors, blindfold yourself, spin around until you fall down and puke, stand up. Now try pointing at north. Can you do that? No? Then a "*mems gyro*" can't do that either.

Comment: This question reminds me of Foucault's pendulum; spin
acceleration DOES affect dynamic systems, and Earth's rotation
is detectable even in a closed room.

Comment: @Whit3rd Right. Now try to detect it with MEMS gyro *and* make the necessary calculations to find the north *and* do it in reasonable time...

Comment: @Whit3rd "*..and Earth's rotation is detectable even in a closed room..*". Yeah... and how can I derive what's north if I know my latitude? Because that's more or less the only thing you can derive from Earth's rotation + gyro (assuming you know which direction "up" is).

Comment: @EugeneSh  The pendulum is intrinsically vertical, and only has one sensor.   'MEMs gyro' with three orthogonal sensors is not so limited.   Nail it to a spinning planet, give it a clock.   Vertical is optional.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: in a room that has three positions for a Foucault pendulum, where you can get three values of latitude, I can derive what's north.

Answer (score 3):

MEMS gyros are not (yet) accurate (and stable) enough to do that, but laser-based gyros ([FOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_optic_gyroscope)s and [RLG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_laser_gyroscope)s) are capable of directly measuring the 0.004166°/sec rotation of the Earth and determining the axis of that spin, thereby aligning themselves to true North.

If you'd like to learn more, search on the phrase "Strapdown Gyrocompass Alignment".

Comment: "*true north*". Is north where  the south pole of earth's magnetic field converges? Or is north a point where earth's axis of spin is penetrating? - Maybe it doesn't matter.. It's just the first time I hear "*true* north", which would indicate that the other would be the "*false* north". I wonder if John Snow would be sad if he was King of the false north.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: I can't tell how serious you're being. True north is the Earth's spin axis, of course -- the only "north" that's relevant to navigation. Magnetic north is used as an approximation only because it's easy to measure with a compass.

Comment: No, I was being serious - Woaw, I never knew that. Now when you're saying it, it kind of makes sense.

Comment: I thought he also asked "in jest".  Google "compass deviation" and  you'll see the difference may be 5-6 degrees.

Comment: With an RLG or FOG, does heading only alignment require a maneuver, or rotation of the platform for alignment?

Comment: Where I live (New England USA), magnetic deviation (declination) is about 17 degrees! If you want to know more about that, check out the [World Magnetic Model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Magnetic_Model) maintained by the U.S. National Geophysical Data Center. And no, a laser gyro does not need a maneuver of any sort -- it measures the spin directly. It just needs a few minutes of integration time to get a good answer.